# Protect PHP Scripts from unauthorized access

Tags: php, ms-access, nginx

I'm currently developing a set of php scripts that act as a private API that is only to be used by some authorized machines.
The scripts interface directly with the MySQL database so I must make sure that no public unauthorized access, as in making the scripts run successfully, is possible.

I've been considering the different alternatives but I decided to come here for some different opinions.

I'm running with nginx.

The API is used externally by a C# program (using WebClient) and a few other servers, which IPs may change, so I was avoiding a IP based approach.

I was considering passing a "key" parameter through post to check for a match

```
if($_POST['key'] == 'key')
```

There are probably better alternatives, what you do think?

Comment: HTTP Basic Auth is more semantically correct than a `key` POST parameter. Also use HTTPS to prevent MITM attacks. Finally, if the C# application can be accessed by a malicious party, all bets are off because the secret can simply be reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure TLS authorization using client certificates:

- http://nginx.org/r/ssl_client_certificate
- http://nginx.org/r/ssl_verify_client

Flexible and secure.

Here is a tutorial: http://blog.nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the key method you wrote but I definitely believe in a defense in depth method. SO I would add some server level protection, check out nginx access control methods. maybe something like:

deny: all
allow IP: 127.0.0.1

Comment: `deny: all allow IP: 127.0.0.1` --- I would shut the whole server down then.

Comment: Surely you would whitelist whichever IP's need to access the server. You can even specify the specific file w/ nginx to apply these rules to.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either a public/private key authentication or use a username and password/api key for each client. Only other option IMO would be using LDAP or other directory authentication, which likely isn't ideal for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic HTTP auth, but this method is not 100% secure, it is vulnerable to middle man attacks

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

http://evertpot.com/223/